# How to get an item's rank in an ActiveRecord collection, with ties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a collection of @players, ordered by total_points. I'm trying to figure out what position a specific @player is ranked in the collection of @players.

Example: there are 5 players, here are their total_points:

- Player 1: 20 points
- Player 2: 20 points
- Player 3: 15 points
- Player 4: 15 points
- Player 5: 15 points

Given that we measure ties like this:

- Player 1: Tied for 1st
- Player 2: Tied for 1st
- Player 3: Tied for 3rd
- Player 4: Tied for 3rd
- Player 5: Tied for 3rd

What's the easiest way to ***only*** show Player 4's rank? Is this possible without iterating through the entire collection? I have an idea of how I would print out the entire list by checking if the previous iterator's total_score is the same, but I don't need to display the whole list, just the rank for the current player.

In my app, there are going to be close to a thousand players, so I'm trying to find a method that will be fast to calculate.

EDIT:

Here's what I've come up with based on @max's answer:

```
 @grouped_players = Player.all.reorder(total_points: :desc).group(:total_points).count
 our_rank = 0
 tied = false
 @grouped_players.each do |points, count|
   if points > @player.total_points
     our_rank += count
   end
   if points == @player.total_points
     our_rank += 1
     if count > 1
       tied = true
     end
     break
   end
 end

 puts our_rank
 puts tied
```

Anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how the points are related to the player in the class?

Comment: @tibsar total_points is just an attribute on the Player class

Comment: As I mentioned, "Then you *select* which elements from the hash have keys greater than your current player's score, *sum* the *values*, and add 1." Added italics here to point out what methods you can use to make it simpler to read.

Comment: To find out whether there's a tie, just check whether `@grouped_players[@player.total_points]` is greater than 1. No need to do it while iterating.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically trying to find out how many players have scores higher than the current player's score, then adding 1. If `total_points` is a database attribute, you should be able to call `Player.group(:total_points).count`, which in your example case should return `{ 20 => 2, 15 => 3 }`. Then you select which elements from the hash have keys greater than your current player's score, sum the values, and add 1. You could do some parts of the process in the database instead of Ruby if you wanted to; that might be more efficient if you have a lot of different scores (and thus the hash returned is quite big). But with 1000 players, I don't see it being a big issue either way unless you're making the calculation awfully frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Active Record group` method like following.
Let you have `Player` model with column `point` that will be used for measuring rank. So, the query will be like

`Player.where(point: Player.group(:point).sort[3])`

You can see [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) that `group` return array. We are sorting to make sure `4th` position will be on index 3. Now use 4th position point to search all user. Keep in mind that if there is no `4th` position on data then it will search for user with `null` value. So, make sure every user has point at least `0`. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what position the user is in. I'm trying to find out their position, with that tie logic mentioned above.